# How can I update the values of a global object inside of a function and then access its values with another function in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update the values of a global object inside of a function and then access it with another function in JS, with no success, my code is as follows:

```js
var doguinho = {
    nome : "",
    idade : "",
    raca : "",
    coloracao : ""
};

$(document).ready(() => {

    $('button[name="btn-enviar"]').click(() => {
        doguinho.nome = $('input[id="input-nome"]').val();
        doguinho.idade = $('input[id="input-idade"]').val();
        doguinho.raca = $('input[id="input-raca"]').val();
        doguinho.coloracao = $('input[id="input-coloracao"]').val();
    })

    $('button[name="btn-mostrar"]').click(() => {
        alert(doguinho.nome);
    })
}
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" id="input-nome"></input>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="input-idade"></input>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="input-raca"></input>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="input-coloracao"></input>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" name="btn-enviar">save</button>
  <button type="submit" name="btn-mostrar">alert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As the object is declared in the global context shouldn't I be able to update ant then read its value from anywhere?

If not, how can I do so?

Comment: It does however it may not show value in alert on first click as you defined two listener to one button at the same time

Comment: Yes, that should work: https://jsfiddle.net/anied/aug8wLx7/1/

Comment: code works for me.

Comment: try to access it using the window object        `window.doguinho`

Comment: @AlexanderNied I just copy-pasted your js and still it doesn't work for me, you can se my full code here: https://github.com/raschmitt/tranigcsharp/tree/master/10_18/Exercicio01

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ just tried, it doesn't work

Comment: @ASDFGerte my code or Alexander's code?

Comment: I edited your post by adding some html so it can be run inside SO, and it works for me here. What is the error/behavior you observe on your not-working side anyways?

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt your code works for me !!

Comment: @ASDFGerte you can see my full code here: https://github.com/raschmitt/tranigcsharp/tree/master/10_18/Exercicio01 I have just copy-pasted Alexander's fiddle to it (wich works at JsFiddle for me), and still it doesn't update the value on my local code, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ can you check my full code on GitHub? As I mentioned it is not working locally.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't update the value"? Do you always get an empty alert? What do you see in a debugger?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, I'm always getting an empty value. I have debugged my code, It updates the value inside the first function, but then when I try to access it from the other function it just returns me the original value.

Comment: the issue is your button refreshes the page.

Comment: @ASDFGerte how can I correct it?

Comment: on your click handlers, use the argument, and do `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` at the end: `$('button[name="btn-enviar"]').click((e) => { e.preventDefault(); /* your code */ return false; });`

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt  use `event.preventDefault();` don't forget to set **event** as argument of your click event function

Comment: Guys, I just corrected it by changing the type of my buttons from type="submit" to type="button", and now it works fine. I will update the question and its answer thanks a lot.

Comment: that works too, also fixes the issue of the page refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte) pointed out in the comments, the problem was with my buttons that were refreshing the page when clicked.

I solved it by changing it's type from type="submit" to type="button".

Anyone interested can check my full code [here](https://github.com/raschmitt/tranigcsharp/tree/master/10_18/Exercicio01).